# How to use Spring's i18n mechanism?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I added localization to my Spring project and it appears to be working but I wonder how I change the language, if the language choice is done based on the browser setting, the HTTP header, a cookie or something else. Is there a way to be explicit as well e.g. taking the locale as a parameter in a way like e.g. `hl=de` on the HTTP query string? I also want to allow the user to set the language on a settings page, how can I do that? My implementation looks like this and writes messages in English:

`<h4 class="title"><fmt:message key="login.title"/></h4>`

servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

So how can I

a) Make the locale choice explicit by enabling overriding the locale with a HTTP GET parameter such as `hl=de` for German and `hl=fr` for French?

b) Let a user choose locale?

### Update

The interceptor is not working. The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="sv" />
</bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="language" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) you defined a bean with id localeChangeInterceptor:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
```

this interceptor enable you to change your locale using the param you choose (in this case: "lang") in your query string (ie: http://mydomain.com/mypage?lang=fr for french)

b) you can provide users link for changing locale using point a)
c) you selected a default locale: "en". otherwhise locale is choosen using browser language

NOTE: you should use `<spring:message code="${msg.value}" arguments="${msg.args}"/>`for your localized string, not fmt, for more integration with spring...

Comment: Thanks. But switching languages is not working and I don't know why. There must be some mistake in my code since the localization does never change, it is always the default even though I use the locale change parameter `lang=fr`. Why?

Comment: for locale resolver bean i used:
`<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
  <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
 </bean>`

furthermore, try with:
`<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
   <property name="paramName" value="language" />
  </bean>
  </mvc:interceptors>`

Comment: @EmanueleRighetto Thanks but I still get the default language even though I put `?language=sv` to the URL and have localization in files `messages_sv.properties` and `messages_en.properties`. Why? I'll try and change the default value and see what it does, but I haven't been able to get other messages than the default English ones.

Comment: I can change the default language so the localizations and deployed. It's just that the HTTP GET parameter doesn't do what it's supposed to. I'm digging through my code to see what is not right. There might be some other place in my project that does something with all request parameters for some reason, but I don't think so. It's also unlikely that the XML is incorrect since incorrect XML would have broken the build or the tests.

Comment: it seems the interceptor isn't being called.. you could try to subclass it and place some debug..

Comment: @EmanueleRighetto Yes, and I have several XML files and I'm not sure where to troubleshoot except like you mention that I can subclass it and debug but I thiought that maybe one can find in my other xml files som eoverriding or similar that could be causing the interceptor not to get called? Because it worked switching the default locale, then that means that the XML was indeed deployed from that file and that the localization files are loaded. If I subclass and debug it, where should I look and what should I look for?

Comment: try to override the preHandle(..) method and place there debug code (remember to return true, otherwise the request will not be fowarded to controller..)

Answer (score 2):

You already have configured the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`. Its parameter `paramName` (you set it to `lang`) is the request parameter that changed the locale.

change the configuration to `hl`, then you can use this parameter to change it:

```
 <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
     <property name="paramName" value="hl" />
 </bean>
```

to let the user change the local, you only need to add some link to the page

```
<a href="${currentPage}?hl=de">German</a>
```

@See [JavaDoc: `LocalChangeInterceptor#setParamName`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html#setParamName%28java.lang.String%29)