# How to read properties file according to the language just set by the user (in a spring application)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm creating a little web application in Spring. I created 2 properties files, italian and english.

With links like `<a href="?lang=it">IT</a>` the user can select the language.

In my file-servlet.xml I have this

```
......
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" >
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
........
```

I have no problem getting the right value when using  `<spring:message code="XXX"/>`, but i dont understand how to get the right value, according to the language set by the user, when I'm "inside" a class.

I was trying to do something like this :

```
ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("messages.xml");
String s = context.getMessage("intestazione",null, Locale.getDefault()));
```

The problem is that with `Locale.getDefault()` iI get the Locale of the JVM and not the language set by the user.

Comment: Looks like duplicate: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638191/how-to-use-springs-i18n-mechanism

Comment: Can't you simply define Locale as one of the parameters of any of your controller mapping method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the current Locale injected into a controller method by simply declaring it as a parameter. Alternatively you could use LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().

Answer (score 0):

If you can access `HttpServletRequest` form class, try like this

```
String s = context.getMessage("intestazione",null, request.getLocale()));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but by using request.getLocale() it seems that i get the JVM Locale and not the Locale set by the user on my web application.